# how to make a button that when clicked opens a transparent popup

Tags: button, popup, screen, transparent

Hi so I am starting a new site and I have an idea of how I want it to be but I was wondering, how do you make a box with a little circle on the bottom left saying "read more" and when clicked a transparent box will open in the middle of their screen showing some more content. I don't even know where to begin, would I use JQuery?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well nothing yet I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [JQuery plugin called Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox). It is pretty simple to use and it does what you are looking for.

Comment: I think it is! Thanks for the help appreciate it.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, then you should mark it as the right answer.